# load ppm file using glut

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to do a texture mapping to a PPM file in C++. Is there some way I can load the PPM file. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the only answer you got is pretty accurate. Why not accept?

Answer (score 3):

PPM is a trivial image file format to read; it's well documented [here](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html).
A few lines of C++ are all you need: [example](http://www.cs.unr.edu/~bebis/CS308/Code/RGB/ReadImage.cpp).